# Bootstrap btn-group alignment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am trying to align my `btn-group` control which essentially is a `Dropdown` next to two buttons.

This is what I currently get:

[image]

I don't want the `Dropdown` to be on the next line. I want it to be on the same line.
These buttons are withing a `<td>` tag which is obviously part of a `<tr>`, `<table>`.

I have developed this in ASP.NET MVC:

```
<td>
   @Html.ActionLink(..Edit Button..)
   @Html.ActionLink(..Delete Button..)
   <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-mini" data-toggle="dropdown">Move Listing <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         <li>@Ajax.ActionLink(...)</li>
         <li>@Ajax.ActionLink(...)</li>
         <li>@Ajax.ActionLink(...)</li>
         <li>@Ajax.ActionLink(...)</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</td>
```

**Update**: Bootstrap CSS

```
.btn-group {
  position: relative;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn-group:first-child {
  *margin-left: 0;
}

.btn-group + .btn-group {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.btn-group > .btn + .dropdown-toggle {
  *padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  *padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
          box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.btn-group > .btn-mini + .dropdown-toggle {
  *padding-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  *padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

There are more but these would be the focal point.

**Update**: HTML

```
<td>
   <a class="btn btn-mini" href="...">Edit</a>
   <a class="btn btn-mini" href="...">Delete</a>
   <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-mini" data-toggle="dropdown">Move Listing <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         <li><a ...">Down</a></li>
         <li><a ...">Bottom</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</td>
```

**Update** display:inline; added via Inspect Element

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `div.btn-group` could be defaulting to `display:block`. Adding a css rule to change it to `display:inline` might fix it:

```
td .btn-group {
    display: inline;
}
```

Update: as per the discussion, the `.btn-group` div needs `display: inline` adding into one of the less files, which then need to be recompiled so that the css output is updated with the new style rule.

Comment: I tried the all the above but it's still not level with the Edit and Delete buttons.

Comment: What style rules are being applied to the div and ul? Something could be overriding the rules that you have set. Use Chrome tools/Firebug to check the actual styles applied. Also, if you set a much larger width on the td does it still wrap?

Comment: I've already tried using Chrome tools. I actually unchecked pretty much every css rule concerning the btn-group but it still wasn't next to the other two buttons. I even extended the <td> width to 700 but that doesn't help either. I have updated my original post. Please check it out.

Comment: Could you also please include the HTML markup generated by the razor code for the td and its contents?

Comment: Yep - it's already in my post under: "I have developed this in ASP.NET MVC:"

Comment: Given that Bootstrap css is built from less files, are your rules definitely being generated in the css output after the bootstrap rules? Just a thought...

Comment: No, that's the MVC Razor source markup - I mean the actual HTML output that is displayed in the browser - that's what the css rules are being applied against, not the Razor source. There may be something in the markup generated for the Action Links affecting the dropdown

Comment: `.btn-group` doesn't have `display: inline` according to your style snippet so will still be block level. Add `!important` to the style rule and ensure that it's being applied via Chrome tools to rule that one out.

Comment: I added display: inline !important; But it didn't work. So I went to Chrome, did an inspect element and noticed it wasn't added to the CSS rules. So I added it in manually and it worked! I think you're right in the sense that it needs to be compiled.

Comment: Yes - if you're adding it to a less file you'll need some kind of less compiler to regenerate the css output. I use Mindscape Web Workbench but you have to pay for that. There are some free ones knocking about I think. Glad you got it working

Comment: Just need to get it compiled now and remove that margin, although I can't really see any margin applied to the button.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help levelnis. Very kind.